# Docker - FROM requires either one or three arguments error from spyder

Tags: docker, spyder

I struggle creating dockerfile in Spyder IDE.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY . /app
RUN make /app
CMD python /app/app.py
```

This is a simple dockerfile from [`docker`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) website.

When I run

```
docker build -t test .
```

I got

`Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 1: FROM requires either one or three arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems related to copy/paste into spyder.

I opened the file using vim and then i saw this (in only one line while it is presented in 4 lines in spyder)

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04^MCOPY . /app^MRUN make /app^MCMD python /app/app.py
```

Just remove the `^M` and put each statement at a new line fix the problem